# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent

Tags: java, android

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en android y me sale un error:

the error in the debbuger:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.android.octa.appprueba3, PID: 4131
>                     Theme: themes:{}
>                     android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.DIAL dat=999999999 }
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1805)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1514)
>                         at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3930)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
>                         at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3890)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
>                         at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4213)
>                         at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4181)
>                         at com.android.octa.appprueba3.SecondActivity$1.onClick(SecondActivity.java:39)
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21158)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_CONTACTS" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

my code, this is the mainAtivity:

```
   package com.android.octa.appprueba3;

  import android.content.Intent;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     private Button bt;


     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
   bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

       Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent1);

       }
   });

    }
}
```

the secondActivity:

```
package com.android.octa.appprueba3;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText editPhoneText;
    private ImageButton imageCallButton;
    private final int PHONE_CALL_CODE = 100;


    @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        editPhoneText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);
      imageCallButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageCallButton1);



    imageCallButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,  Uri.parse("999999999"));
                startActivity(i);
           }
       });

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El error indica que no existe un intent para manipular correctamente la información:

> No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.DIAL

veo que tienes definido el permiso:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Pero revisando el código estas definiendo el `Intent` incorrectamente:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,  Uri.parse("999999999"));
```

debe ser:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,  Uri.parse("tel:999999999"));
```

---

Debes agregar el protocolo `tel:`

```
Uri.parse("tel:" + numerotelefonico)
```