# ACTION_DIAL no ejecuta en boton - Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Tengo un problema con la ejecucion del ACTION_DIAL, quiero ir mediante un intent a la interfaz para llamar en androi, Pero al ejecutarlo en el emulador no toma el metodo

```
 public void Llamar(View view) {

    String phoneNumber = "3166160988";
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    intent2.setData(parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
    if (intent2.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent2);
    }

}
```

Ademas tengo este permiso en el manifest:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realizalo de esta forma:

```
String phoneNumber = "3166160988";
Uri call = Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber);
Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, call);
startActivity(intent2);
```

Recuerda que no se realizara el marcado (por seguridad) solo abrira el telefono y agregara el numero para tu puedas realizar la marcacion, tu telefono debe tener soporte telefonico.

revisa:

[android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/47282/android-content-activitynotfoundexception-no-activity-found-to-handle-intent/47284#47284)

Comment: Me marca el siguiente error:
at com.example.proyecto_comidas.MainActivity.op_lamar(MainActivity.java:60)

la linea 60 es:
startActivity(intent2);

mi API es 16

Comment: El metodo  llamar donde se encuentra? si se encuentra en una Activity puedes usar getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent2); si te encuentras en un Fragment usa getActivity().startActivity(intent2);  , especifica que error se muestra, me parece que puede ser el contexto.